# I need to filter ag-grid data while ag-grid loading completed

Tags: angular, ag-grid

i have a ag-grid and i need to filter this grid data immediately after grid is loaded i found a workaround with i can call my filterData method with setTimeout but thats terrible if grid is loaded before timeout then data will not filter if grid is loaded after timeout then data will not be filter.

Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: why are you racing with ag-grid, show a loader and only push when the data is filtered.

Comment: @vaira ag-grid is already there and i cant remove that , i am calling my filterData(which is filtering data)  method from onGridReady callback method.

i tried to call  filterData method from setTimeout and i put 4 second as timeout then i am able to get data by getColumnState() method and filtered data was showing in ag-grid

Comment: please provide what you have tried and explain your question clearly. Do you want to filter after grid is ready then you can use " this.gridApi.setQuickFilter('keyword'); "

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. Reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.

Comment: @FaisalAfroz thanks for reply ...  but i have resolved this issue , actually i was trying to  call getColumnState() before grid loading its data so  i have written a method to check if grid is loaded successfully or not . if grid is loaded successfully then call getColumnState()...